# Check Tabs visited in p:tabView. Usage of onTabShow Event?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to track in a controller-bean, which tabs of a *p:tabView* were already visited (by tab-id).
I don't want to use the *onTabChange* event for some reasons (blocked already for other things).
So I tried to realize my usecase with **onTabShow** event of *p:tabView*. But did not succeed yet. I first tried with p:ajax listener:

```
<p:tabView>
  <p:ajax event="tabShow" listener="#{myBean.checkTab(event)}" .../>
```

Result was error-message: *tabShow* not supported in p:ajax ...

Second try was using *remoteCommand*:

```
<p:tabView onTabShow="myCommand()">
...
<p:remoteCommand name="myCommand" actionListener="#{myBean.checkTab}" .../>
```

But how to pass the event as parameter to my bean-method to get the tab-object from?

Does somebody can help or has another idea how I can track the visited tabs in my bean?
With a binding of tabView perhaps? But how?

Thanks!

Comment: So the first time someone selects a tab you would like to track it? Would you like to just log the index of the tab or what would you like to do with it?

Comment: I want to ensure, that all not-disabled tabs are visited before enabling a save button. So I would like to track the id's of the tabs visited by a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `<p:ajax/>` without specifying an `event`. That being said, you can get the currently selected tab either by

1. Binding the `activeIndex` property on the `<p:tabView/>` to a backing bean property

   ```
   <p:tabView activeIndex="#{bean.selectedTabIndex}">
         <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.checkTab}" .../>
    </p:tabView>
   ```

   With this variable bound, you can use it in `checkTab`.
2. Use the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` object to access the specific tab selected:

   ```
   public void checkTab(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe){
      TabView tb = (TabView) abe.getComponent();
      List<Tab> loadedTabs =  tb.getLoadedTabs();
      Tab theTab = loadedTabs.get(tb.getActiveIndex());
   }
   ```

   and in your view:

   ```
   <p:tabView>
       <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.checkTab}"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, I tried that already. _tabShow_ -event is not supported in **<p:ajax/>**. At least in PF 3.4.x. But if that has changed in 3.5 then sorry for that I did not mention the PF version, that we are using.

Comment: @user2894170 - my mistake, the code samples could have been clearer. See my update